# Send commands to a remote ssh server from my website form

Tags: python, html, ssh, server

I want to create a website that users can fill a form,

and then I send those parameters to a remote ssh server to issue a python script.

Example, in my webpage, the form contains input text, para1, para2, para3, etc..

After the user clicks submit, it should be able to send a command to remote ssh server terminal "python para1, para2, para3,....."

What kind of technique that I need to solve this problem??

Thank you.

Comment: What web framework are you using? Typically, you would use a background job for something like this. The main background job system for python is [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Web application using Flask Framework and then use the 
Paramiko module to connect Python script with SSH Server and execute 
commands from the local machine. Your python script will act as an SSH 
client.

Check out this link which shows steps to create a web application using Python and Flask Framework:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-python-flask-and-mysql--cms-22972

Web application Example:
For you simple form, you can update home page and sign up page to get 
form parameters and use those parameters to pass commands to the SSH server.

Please find below the link for Paramiko and one link showing examples. It is really easy to set up the Paramiko.

```
try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)

    client.connect(hostname, port=port, username=username, password=password)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    print stdout.read(),

finally:
    client.close()
```

Here, the hostname will be the SSH server and the username and password will be the one which you usually use to connect to the SSH server.

Paramiko - http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/
Example - https://gist.github.com/mlafeldt/841944