# Display message from remote ssh server to my html page with Python web framework

Tags: python, html, flask, server, paramiko

I use **Python flask and paramiko** to execute command on my remote ssh server from my html form.

It should to display the message back to my html file:

> (result from the executed file in ssh server)

Any Idea or Website Link are welcoming

Thank you.

Comment: You have asked this question two times before already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59992524/850848 + https://stackoverflow.com/q/60031659/850848

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this within a function. Once the function is called return the "output" to the html.

```
import sys, paramiko


if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    print "args missing"
    sys.exit(1)

hostname = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
command = sys.argv[3]

username = "admin"
port = 22

try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())

    client.connect(hostname, port=port, username=username, password=password)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    output = stdout.read(),

finally:
    client.close()
```